# Is it possible to use a RabbitMessagingTemplate as AmqpOutboundEndpoint?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-amqp

i'm very new to `spring-integration`. I'm trying to integrate an `IntegrationFlow` which endpoint is an `AmqpOutboundEndpoint`:

```
return IntegrationFlows.from("ordersChannel")
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
                    .exchangeName(exchangeName)
                    .routingKey(routingKey))
            .get();
```

My `MessageGateway` creates instances of type `org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage` with my desired payload:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OrderDispatchService {


    @Gateway(requestChannel = "ordersChannel")
    void sendOrder(final Order order);
}
```

And i do want that the outboundEndpoint creates amqp messages exactly like `RabbitMessagingTemplate` does. A `org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage` looking amqp message.
But the `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` just takes an `AmqpTemplate` as argument. How can i achieve this? Any attempt to transform the original message fails because the endpoint simply unwraps the message and just takes the original payload. Maybe i am off the track?

UPDATE:

I did the following now:

```
.enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h
                    .put(AmqpHeaders.MESSAGE_ID, "headers.id.toString()")
                    .put(AmqpHeaders.TIMESTAMP, "new java.util.Date(headers.timestamp)")))
```

This copies the values of the original `org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage` headers to the equivalent amqp headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean; the `RabbitMessagingTemplate` performs a similar function to the `AmqpOutboundEndpoint` - converts a `o.s.messaging.Message` to a RabbitMQ message.

The both use a `RabbitTemplate` under the covers.

The `RabbitMessagingTemplate` is for people using spring-messaging but not using Spring Integration.

If you can explain exactly what your problem is, we can help further.

Comment: The ```RabbitMessagingTemplate``` creates a RabbitMQ message which is identical to the original ```o.s.messaging.Message```. But the ```AmqpOutboundEndpoint``` creates a message which just contains the original payload of the ```o.s.messaging.Message```. And i want to use spring-integration for message handling/creation with the ability to use an outbound channel adapter to rabbitMQ which sends/converts ```o.s.messaging.Message```s the same way like ```RabbitMessagingTemplate``` does. I hope i could explain my problem a bit better.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "identical"; one is an `o.s.m.Message`, the other is a rabbitmq message so they can't be "identical"; perhaps you are talking about header mapping; Spring Integration doesn't map user-defined headers by default, but you can instruct it to do so by adding `.mappedRequestHeaders("*")` to the flow definition.

Comment: yes, i was talking about the headers, the amqp message contains the ```o.s.messaging.message``` header ```id```, ```timestamp``` out of the box if converted by ```RabbitMessagingTemplate```.

Comment: The integration `DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper` doesn't map those headers; you would need to create a subclass of the mapper to do so. Historically, those headers have been internal to SI and they possibly shouldn't have been leaked by the `o.s.messaging` support when it was added to Spring AMQP. Feel free to open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) if you think we should add an option for SI to provide compatible mapping with the `RabbitMessagingTemplate`.

Comment: Good to know that. I'll try that option with subclassing the header mapper. And, maybe, if i dove deeper into spring integration i'll think about an issue.

Comment: ```.enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h
                        .put(AmqpHeaders.MESSAGE_ID, "headers.id.toString()")
                        .put(AmqpHeaders.TIMESTAMP, "new java.util.Date(headers.timestamp)")))
                        .channel("amqpOutboundChannel").get();```

Comment: Yes - that would work too - BTW, it's generally better to edit your question with code, code doesn't render well in comments.